# Spring ModelMap object for all methods

Tags: java, spring

For better understanding, that`s a sample Spring Controller code:

```
@Controller  
public class SampleController {  
    protected String URL = "http://www.google.com/";    


    @RequestMapping(value = {listPath}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list1( ModelMap modelMap) {
        modelMap.addAttribute("url", URL);
        return "list1View";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {listPath}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list2( ModelMap modelMap) {
        modelMap.addAttribute("url", URL);
        return "list2View";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {listPath}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list3( ModelMap modelMap) {
        modelMap.addAttribute("url", URL);
        return "list3View";
    }

}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Pass this URL ModelMap object to all methods without pass in all methods?

Answer (score 1):

Try using @ControllerAdvice in combination with @ModelAttribute method if you want to pass common values for all you controllers returned models.

Here is a quick explanation.

> Use @ModelAttribute at the method level to provide reference data for
>   the model. @ModelAttribute annotated methods are executed before the
>   chosen @RequestMapping annotated handler method. They effectively
>   pre-populate the implicit model with specific attributes, often loaded
>   from a database. Such an attribute can then already be accessed
>   through @ModelAttribute annotated handler method parameters in the
>   chosen handler method, potentially with binding and validation applied
>   to it. In other words; a method annotated with @ModelAttribute will
>   populate the specified “key” in the model. This happens BEFORE the
>   @RequestMapping At Method Parameter level

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HandlerInterceptor and add objects to the RequestScope for all requests.

```
public class MyHandlerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    request.addAttribute("url", "some url");

    return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
  }

}
```

In your Web Application Context Configuration (`mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`):

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
        <bean class="com.example.project.MyHandlerInterceptor"/>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```